# unable to access jarfile using java Runtime from another jar on linux platform

Tags: java, linux, jar

I am trying to run an executable jar from another jar using **Runtime.exec** function from java class.
Code is

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("java -jar \""+_JarPath +"\" "  + "\""+ args[0]+"\""+ " " +"\""+ args[1]+"\""+ " " +"\""+ args[2]+"\"" + " " +"\""+ args[3]+"\"");
```

Here, argument `args`are not null and are well defined.

This code runs fine on Windows platform but on Linux, I am getting error

> Unable to access jarfile "/opt/mydir/lib/MyFol/mytest.jar"

I have read other similar questions and made sure that

1. The directory `/opt/mydir/lib/MyFol/` and file `mytest.jar` are having all the permission
2. The executable jar from which this process command is launched is also having all the permissions.
3. User on linux is also admin

I am using **OpenJDK** on Linux.

Comment: maybe the `jar` which you are using has been corrupted?

Comment: @stsd no not at all......

Comment: Please post the full error message. It looks strange that you have a double quote character at the start but not at the end.

Comment: I had similar observation.Please post full trace

Comment: @RobinGreen no the double quotes is at end too I forgot to put it.....

Comment: @vels4j read the question I have mentioned I have already checked the permission of directory /opt/mydir/lib/MyFol/ and jar mytest.jar and also on jar form where I issue the command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without the double quotes. I suspect it may be an issue that the shell is not being invoked, but rather Java is being invoked directly.

Comment: but if I remove double quotes then how I will escape the empty spaces in between..... let me try this also.....

Comment: @dbw That is why there is another overload of exec(). And, allow me to say this: naming a file with blanks in it is just stupid.

Comment: @Ingo but the file name is not containing blanks it is the full path that and other arguments which are supplied they contains blanks but thanks for providing an easy solution which I could not find, and then I went to big circle of finding another solution...... Thanks.....

Answer (score 5):

The actual problem with the above code on linux machine was the double quotes, as stated by Robin Green in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873679/unable-to-access-jarfile-using-java-runtime-from-another-jar-on-linux-platform/19874058#19874058), and he is right.
**But then I was unable to run jar when the path contained empty spaces or other arguments were having spaces in between.**
For that I had to try some other way to load jars, which could work seamless in both the platforms and had the problem of spaces removed too.
**Process Builder** came to rescue, in this situation.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", _JarPath, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
Process p = pb.start();
```

This worked fine on both the platforms without any probes, in all the situations.

**EDIT**
OOPS an easy solution was there but I did not got it, Thanks to **Ingo** for the [comment posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873679/unable-to-access-jarfile-using-java-runtime-from-another-jar-on-linux-platform/19874058#comment29660826_19874058) that we can pass the arguments by using another overloaded function of `exec`

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p =null;
String[] cmdarray = new String[7];
cmdarray[0] = "java";
cmdarray[1] = "-jar";
cmdarray[2] = _JarPath;                 
cmdarray[3] = args[0];
cmdarray[4] = args[1];
cmdarray[5] = args[2];
cmdarray[6] = args[3];
p = r.exec(cmdarray);
```